# How to specify module path in node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am very new in Node.js, I installed angularjs and expressjs with bower, and I have app structure as below:

```
--parking
    --server.js
    --bower_components
        --angular
        --express
            --lib
               --express.js
```

In server.js, I want to import express module, How can I specify express module path in server.js, Could you give me some suggestions?

Comment: `--expres.js` seems like a typo, is it?

Comment: sorry, I already edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express is a Node.js module and it should be installed with `npm` instead bower:

```
$ npm install express --save
```

Then you simple require it in your server.js:

```
var express = require(express);
```

As per reference: [Installing Express](http://expressjs.com/starter/installing.html) and [Basic example](http://expressjs.com/starter/hello-world.html)

Comment: This help me very much, and I wonder why install angularjs with bower not npm

Comment: Because AngularJS is a client side library while express is a server side one